# What is wrong on inline values?

Tags: vega-lite

The ["line chart" demo](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/line.html) works fine, and is expressed in javascript, as in [getting_started.html](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/tutorials/getting_started.html).

... but **when I replace "data" field from URL to inline values**, it shows only the axys, no chart into.

It works: `"data":{"url":"https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/data/stocks.csv"},`

It **not** works:

```js
var vlSpec = {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "data":  {"values": [
      {"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Jan 1 2000","price":39.81},
      {"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Feb 1 2000","price":36.35},
      {"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Mar 1 2000","price":43.22},
      {"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Apr 1 2000","price":28.37},
      {"symbol":"MSFT","date":"May 1 2000","price":25.45}
  ]},
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
};
```

There are an error at console, that not make sense:

*WARN Infinite extent for field "date": [Infinity, -Infinity]*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your specification only contains rows with `symbol="MSFT"`. It also contains a filter transform, `{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}`, which removes all rows except those with `symbol="GOOG"`. The result is there is no data left to plot.

The warning you see comes from the fact that axis extent is determined from the data, and when there is no data, the extent is left at `[-Infinity, Infinity]`.

If you remove or modify this filter statement, the chart will work. For example:

```
vlSpec = {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "data":  {"values": [
      {"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Jan 1 2000","price":39.81},
      {"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Feb 1 2000","price":36.35},
      {"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Mar 1 2000","price":43.22},
      {"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Apr 1 2000","price":28.37},
      {"symbol":"MSFT","date":"May 1 2000","price":25.45}
  ]},
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='MSFT'"}],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
};
```

The result looks like this ([Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-SAA)):

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to disable the warning if there's no data to plot? It is causing thousands of warnings to be logged, for example on https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/interactive_multi_line_pivot_tooltip

Answer (score 1):

Need only to comment the "magic line"

`//  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],`

---

Please explain!  This is a Wiki answer

Answer (score 0):

According to the Vega [docs](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/types/#Date) for the Date type, the date needs to be a valid Javascript Date object or timestamp.

> A valid JavaScript `Date` object or timestamp. As JSON does not support date values natively, within a Vega specification a date-time value can be expressed either as a numeric timestamp (the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch, as produced by the Date.getTime() method) or using a signal expression (such as `{"signal": "datetime(2001, 2, 3)"}`)

Comment: Hi FunnyGopher, I edited the question to simplify and focus on real problem... Seems that is not a problem on dates. Dates in string format, like "Jan 1 2000", are valid ones.